# Inconsistent results from Group-object cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I used powershell in version 2009 and use Group-object in my script.

```
$todaye = (Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00)
$yesterday = $todaye.AddDays(-1)

$EventLogs = 'Operations Manager'
$csv = @()
$strlog = $EventLogs.Split(',')
foreach($log in $strlog)
    {
       $log | ForEach-Object{ get-eventlog -log  $_ -After $yesterday - 
       Before $todaye | Group-Object EventID,EntryType,Source,MachineName,
    {(([String]$_.TimeGenerated) -split " ")[0]},  
    {(([String]$_.TimeGenerated) -split " ")[1]}, $_ -NoElement | 
              Sort-Object Count -Descending | 
              Select-Object count,name  | ForEach-Object{
       $properties = @{
        'ServerName' = ($_.Name -split ", ")[3];
        'day' = (($_.Name -split ", ")[4] -split " ")[0];
        'time' = (($_.Name -split ", ")[5]);
        'EventID' = ($_.Name -split ", ")[0];
        'EventType' = ($_.Name -split ", ")[1];
        'Source'    = ($_.Name -split ", ")[2];
        'Count' = $_.Count;

       }
    $psobject = new-object psobject -Property $properties
    $csv += $psobject
          }
       }
    }
```

after I run my script I have the below error.

```
Group-Object : Cannot convert System.Management.Automation.PSObject to one
of the following types {System.String, 
System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
```

I run my script in powersell 2012 and didn't any errors. how can I do for solve this error.

Comment: `{(([String]$_.TimeGenerated) -split " ")[1]}, $_ -NoElement` -> `{(([String]$_.TimeGenerated) -split " ")[1]} -NoElement`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `$_` from the second `{(([String]$_.TimeGenerated)` line then it will work on powershell 2 as well
like this:

```
{(([String]$_.TimeGenerated) -split " ")[1]} -NoElement
```